# Simple http server

Tags: node.js

Well, this might be a stupid question, but i'm as n00b as i can be, regarding node.

I set up a server, with the code we can find in any node presentation or tutorial...

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log('connection from: ' res.socket.remoteAddress);

    res.writeHead(200, ['Content-Type', 'text/plain']);
    res.write('Hello ');
    res.end('World');
});

server.listen('8080');
```

My question is, why does my server logs my message twice for every request i make from the browser?

Comment: you should probably remove the node tag from this question and just leave the node.js tag. See the node tag description for details.

Comment: And the "thanks" are not necessary :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your browser is requesting an img to use in the upper corner favicon.

Comment: oh, ok... i wouldn't get to the answer alone, in a million years, thanks

Comment: try a `console.log(req)` lots of interesting info in there.

Answer (score 6):

As @megakorre says, it's the default browser behaviour in respect of favicons. It's mentioned in [The Node Beginner Book](http://nodebeginner.org/index.html), which is well worth checking out. I too am in the node 'n00b' stage and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend trying out Express (http://expressjs.com/). As a beginner, it really helped me get some core concepts together (simple routing like '/users' and '/users/:id') and it gets rid of some annoyances for you like the double favicon.ico request.

Comment: thanks, i am going to try Express, of course. but i am trying to get the core basics by my own :)