# C Node Native Extension calls method twice

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js

So I am fairly new to C and working on a simple Node Native extension.

Here is the code for my extension called helloworld.c

```
Handle<Value> Method(const Arguments& args) {
  printf(":%s:\n", "Calling Method");
  //SendByte(bdrate,'1');
  HandleScope scope;
  if(toggleLight()==0){
    printf(":%s:\n", "Turning On");
    return scope.Close(String::New("Turned On"));
  }
  else{
printf(":%s:\n", "Turning Off");
return scope.Close(String::New("Turned Off"));
  }
}

void init(Handle<Object> target) {
  printf(":%s:\n", "Init");
  target->Set(String::NewSymbol("hello"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(Method)->GetFunction());
}
NODE_MODULE(helloworld, init)
```

I consume the previous through the following Node.js class...

```
var addon = require('./build/Release/helloworld');

var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write(addon.hello());
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

When I call the site I see the following in my terminal

```
~/Desktop/hellonode$ node testnode
:Init:
:Calling Method:
:Turning Off:
:Calling Method:
:Turning On:
```

Why does it seem to be calling the method twice? I am sure the answer is obvious but I cannot see it.

Comment: Hmm, could you decide whether you are using C or C++? Here, you have mix of C and C++... in .c file. Wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a duplicate. This is not a bug in your extension, it's an issue in your HTTP code.

See:

- [Simple http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973226/simple-http-server)
- [node.js page refresh calling resources twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283801/node-js-page-refresh-calling-resources-twice)

Basically, your browser is requesting two urls, `/` and `/favicon.ico`, and since you aren't checking the URL, it runs your extension code on both requests.